# What's the difference between a "job + UI" context and using "parent = job"?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

The UI Coroutines Guide contains a [section](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md#lifecycle-and-coroutine-parent-child-hierarchy) on how to manage the lifecycle of UI coroutines. It explains we should create a top-level `Job` instance and pass a composite coroutine context, `contextJob + UI` to all coroutines we launch:

```
launch(contextJob + UI, block = block)
```

While implementing this pattern in my project it came natural to me to use `contextJob` as the *parent* instead:

```
launch(UI, parent = contextJob, block = block)
```

I haven't yet tested the difference in behavior, but I'm interested in the semantic difference between these two options. They look very similar to me, but I'd prefer to use the `parent = contextJob` since it's more obvious what it does. Specifically, I note that `parent` is allowed to be `null`, but if I use `+`, I would probably have to use `NonCancellable` as the null-object.

Is there anything wrong with using `contextJob` as the `parent` argument to `launch` or `actor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no semantic difference, neither there will be in the future.

Ability to use `+` operator comes naturally from `coroutineContext` machinery: `Job` is context element, thus it can be appended to the context.

But writing `launch(UI + job)` seems unnatural, because an intention is not clear. What does it even mean to have a concatenation of UI dispatcher and some job?
To make such pattern readable, `parent` parameter was added, `launch(UI, parent = job)` is a more natural way to expose intention to launch job as a child of given parent.
Under the hood, it still concatenates context and parent, but now API looks prettier for users.

Note that same approach could be used for other library's elements, e.g. for `CoroutineExceptionHandler`, but it's a tradeoff: either you have a method with dozen of default parameters, of you sacrifice a readability and write `launch(ctx + myExceptionHandler)`, so it was decided to introduce only `parent` parameter as a most common one.

Comment: Thanks, this answer is spot-on! However, it lacks any authoritative references and your current profile doesn't reveal whether you are a person that can assert such an authoritative answer. Are you a member of the JetBrains team working on this?

Comment: Yes, I'm the member of JetBrains team working on kotlinx.coroutines as well: https://github.com/qwwdfsad